# NACHOS(JAVA verrsion) tutorials [setup and simple sample]

Tags: java, operating-system, systems-programming, nachos

I need to setup NACHOS java version in Linux and run some simple sample . How to setup and run simple sample? need some tutorials and some computer assignment with solution with NACHOS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at:

- The [Nachos for Java README](http://www.assembla.com/code/2009NACHOS/subversion/nodes) - how to get, install, work with NachOS.
- The [Projects and Nachos](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/sp10/Nachos/index.html) link on the left of the [CS162](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/sp10/) home page.

  - Pay a special attention to [How to use Eclipse for 162 projects](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/sp10/Nachos/eclipse/).

Some extras:

- [Installation and configuration of nachos 5.0j for linux](http://www.scribd.com/doc/16503578/Nachos50jLinux200412922) - the document consists mostly of screen captures so it's perfectly "understandable" even if it is in Spanish (I don't speak Spanish but still could get it).
- [Nachos Tutorial](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/2133769/Nachos-Tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it, but I just googled a bit using keywords [java nachos linux](http://google.com/search?q=java+nachos+linux) and came across [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5DY1oRSy84). In the list of "Related videos" there are some more. You may find it useful.

Comment: I see these but I need some sample with solutions.